# integration of QT and win32 c++

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, user-interface

I have developed my code in Win32 project (windows application). The code is about taking binary files, converting to bitmap and then making and animation out of those bitmap. The animation is called in the win32 window (as we do with normal CreateWindow() function procedure)

Now I have to develop the GUI to control the parameters and for GUI I have to developed in QT since the over all system is in QT.

Since mostly I am an FPGA programmer, hence I have not too much idea about integration of different versions of C++ libraries (like win32, win32 console and QT etc.). What can be the program structure, i.e. should the GUI button(s) call the CreateWindow() thread or should I make the .dll of my code?

Any reference in this regard?

Thanks
Kashan

Comment: This question is quite broad, and not a good fit for SO Q&A format... But, some thoughts to help you get started and perhaps refine this or future questions: To keep things simple, you should probably do entire GUI in Qt. That is, remove the native window you have now, instead use Qt to show the images. Qt's `QImage` can take (almost) any raw bitmap format (though RGB32 will give best performance, IIRC, because it doesn't need to be converted to be displayed), and then you can use `QLabel` to display it very simply. For details, study Qt, look at tutorials and examples :)

Comment: hmmm...yes you might be right. But now that I have started with it, it would be a little time-consuming for me to back and start all over again with QT. ^_^  I am already baffled with so many versions and libraries of C++, console, win32, directx programming, QT etc. etc.... so with all of these I chose win32 for generation of movie and QT for overall GUI development

Answer (score 1):

QT uses WIN32 API for most operations in Windows builds. So having code that uses WIN32 isn't a problem.

Your code, of course, will not be portable to other OSes

Comment: thanks

So if I understood it right, it will be like -> make a GUI with QT -> then check the C++ code generate by QT and add our code for win32 there ? right ?

Comment: You can make it a single project or have the win32 api a separate project (lib or dll).